# Create a calculated pivot table column in excel based off other columns in the pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-columns, pivot-chart

So I have a bunch of rows in a query table that shows orders from a certain timeframe and whether that order had a "defect" or not. I have started a pivot table on that table to summarize the # of orders and # of those orders that were defective by day (trying to start a p-chart).

Is there any way to create a 4th column in the pivot table that calculates the percent defective (Orders with Defects/Count of Orders) from the two existing columns?

[image]

Comment: [Calculate a percentage for subtotals in a PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-a-percentage-for-subtotals-in-a-pivottable-6aa66bce-11c5-47f7-b6b6-0959b0b13a72) I think you need the option `% Of` Anyways, you can add the calculus in your source data and just take that field into the pivot table

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns All the % Of options only let me choose the Date column as the base. I am unsure how to calculate from the source data as it is only rows by Order #, Date, and a Defective yes/no field.

Comment: Can you add a data example of the source and expected output in your pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

Based on [this site](https://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html), these are the steps:

- To start, select any cell in the pivot table
- Next, on the Excel Ribbon, go to the PivotTable Analyze tab
- In the Calculations group, click Fields, Items, & Sets
- Then, in the drop-down menu, click the Calculated Field command

Once there give a name to your Calculated Field and set your formula to `Orders with defect / orders` (tip: select the fields from the list to make sure you get the names right).

One last note: I believe calculated fields perform additions by default.. I noticed your 2nd column is a "count", I believe the calculated field will sum that column (before dividing) instead of counting it.